# QT - uncheck check box

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

Guys please let me know how to uncheck the check box using QT C++.

Comment: Please accept answers on some of your old questions, you're much more likely to get helpful feedback!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use

```
QCheckBox::setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [setChecked()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) method from QAbstractButton.

```
QCheckButton b;
b.setChecked( false ); // Uncheck it
```

Alternatively you could use setCheckState() [setCheckState()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcheckbox.html#setCheckState) method from QCheckButton. This gives you the option to 'partially uncheck' it.

```
QCheckButton b;
b.setCheckState( Qt::Unchecked );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code,

QCheckButton chkbox;
chkbox.setChecked( false );

Answer (score 0):

use the ui class of your main-window to get the icon action and uncheck it, eg.

ui->actionDraw_Polygon->setChecked(false);