# How to use QGroupBox and QCheckBoxes to one check another?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand how to use signals to when one `QCheckBox` be checked it uncheck all other checkboxes present in the same `QGroupBox`

```
class GroupBox : public QGroupBox
{
public:

    GroupBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QGroupBox(parent) 
    {

    }

public slots:
    void uncheck();

};



class CheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
public:

    CheckBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QCheckBox(parent) 
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(checked()), this, SLOT(checked()));
    }

public slots:

    void checked()
    {
        qDebug() << "checked";
    }
};
```

When I click on one of the checkboxes it didn't go to the function `checked()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QCheckBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcheckbox.html) inherits from [QAbstractButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html)

You should use [clicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click) or [stateChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcheckbox.html#signals) signal instead of checked.

e.q.

```
 connect(this, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checked(int)));
```

Btw; if using a modern Qt version, you should ditch the `SIGNAL` and `SLOTS` macros and instead use the new `connect()` syntax that's checked at compile time.

Refer: [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

e.p.

```
 connect(this, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &CheckBox::checked);
```

Comment: Thank you, and about how to uncheck the others checkboxes in the same QGroupBox?

Comment: @Raja 
Do [setChecked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) on other checkboxes. A simple sample: [QT - uncheck check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520797/qt-uncheck-check-box)